# How can "new new Something" produce valid results in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I'm currently developing a JavaScript parser and study the [ECMAScript 5.1 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf). Here's a question which puzzles me at the moment.

§ **11.2 Left-Hand-Side Expressions** defines the following `NewExpression` production:

```
NewExpression :
    MemberExpression
    new NewExpression
```

If I read it correctly, then the `NewExpression` may be something like

```
new new Something
```

(Actually, *any* amount of `new`s.)

This puzzles me completely. How could `new Something` potentialy return anything you could once again `new`? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Very cool. What platform are you developing it for?

Comment: @JonathanM No big surprises here - Java, on JavaCC basis. https://github.com/highsource/javascript-codemodel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not common at all, but it is possible; a function that returns a function:

```
function baz(){}
function foo(){return baz}

new new foo() instanceof baz // true
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at section **13.2.2 [[Construct]]** in the specification. More precisely, step 9 of the algorithm.

> 9. If Type(result) is Object then return result.

Functions are objects, so if you return a function from a function and try to instantiate the latter function using `new`, you'll get back the former function, not a new object. But functions are also constructors, so you can `new` the returned function.

```
function bar() {}
function foo() { return bar; }
new foo === bar; // true
```

Comment: this is a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use `new new` when using an object as namespace. Though there will be a nicer way:

Instead of:

```
var Namespace = function() {
    var ClassFirst = this.ClassFirst = function() {
        this.abc = 123;
    }
    var ClassSecond = this.ClassSecond = function() {
        console.log("Cluttered way to access another class in namespace: ", new new Namespace().ClassFirst().abc);
        console.log("Nicer way to access a class in same namespace: ", new ClassFirst().abc);
    }
}

new new Namespace().ClassSecond()
```

Do this:

```
var Namespace = new function() {
    var ClassFirst = this.ClassFirst = function() {
        this.abc = 123;
    }
    var ClassSecond = this.ClassSecond = function() {
        console.log("Cluttered way to access another class in namespace: ", new Namespace.ClassFirst().abc);
        console.log("Nicer way to access a class in same namespace: ", new ClassFirst().abc);
    }
}

new Namespace.ClassSecond()
```

Not directly related to the question, but I was googling `new new javascript`, because it looked pretty ugly and wrong. This post can help to avoid this unneeded object creation for fellow `new new` Google'ers.